# How to automatically create virtual methods from inherited class in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using `QT4.8.4 + Qt Creator 2.8.1`. Now I need to create several classes *Child_X* that inherit from another class *Parent*. In *Parent* I have several virtual methods.
Now I have to implement them in all of my *Child_X* classes. To save editing time, I'd like Qt do that for me automatically. When I remember right there is the possibility to have Qt create all the virtual methods. Does anybody know how?

Thank you

---

Sorry, I did not formulate correctly: I did not mean that Qt will automatically write the body of the methods. ( To invent that would probably make you very rich :-) )

I was talking about Qt writing all the headers of the virtual methods in the newly created (inherited) class. This saves a lot of writing/copying classnames etc.. The body would be empty in all the virtual methods.

Thank you

itelly

Comment: you need different implementation in each child class  for your virtual methods ?

Comment: Why don't you just implement the method in your `Parent` class, if it's simple enough that Qt could auto-implement it?

Comment: Are those abstract methods that you want to implement? Each implementation of each of these methods in the derived classes is different than the others?

Answer (score 10):

I hope you already found it, but maybe for others:

- Right click on the class name in the editor.
- In the menu, click on 'Refactor' and then on 'Insert virtual functions of base classes'.

You can choose to directly make the functions in the implementation file (as well as in the header file).